# PWM fan with PWM wire disconnected

Tags: pwm, fan

What will happen when the supply and ground are connected for a CPU fan with PWM but the PWM wire is not connected? Will the fan run at its full speed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect a 4-pin fan (PWM controllable) to a 3-pin motherboard connector (non-PWM) without issue.

Most fans will simply run at full speed when the PWM pin floats.